# I am getting the node_module like problem how to resolve this

Tags: vue.js

Vue in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Landing.vue, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Signin.vue and 1 other

Comment: Can you update the whole error log

Comment: could you please elaborate on your problem, cause from your question it related to vue-loader problem i.e it is trying to load something which loader can't recognize

Comment: Actually someone gave me a project while I m going for run above error is coming. I don't have enough knowledge of Vue. so could you please tell me where I m doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                              3:04:03 PM

This dependency was not found:

* Vue in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Landing.vue, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Signin.vue and 1 other

Comment: Try `npm i` to install dependency or make sure you imported correctly everything you use in components.